# Schwache Verben mit Konjunktiv II ungleich Indikativ Präteritum?

Tags: subjunctive, conjugation

Ich dachte bisher intuitiv, solche Verben gebe es nicht. Plötzlich lese ich hier:

> Da die Indikativ-Formen des Präteritums mit den Konjunktiv-II-Formen (des Präteritums) bei den meisten schwachen Verben übereinstimmen,...

Hat jemand ein Beispiel? Wie selten sind sie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meines Wissens nach nur diese beiden, die im Präteritum einen anderen Stamm haben:

> **bring**en, **brach**te, **bräch**te
>   **denk**en, **dach**te, **däch**te

Wenn man möchte, kann man die folgenden Präteritopräsentien noch dazunehmen:

> können, konnte, könnte
>   müssen, mußte, müßte
>   dürfen, durfte, dürfte
>   wissen, wußte, wüßte

Ein echter Einzelgänger ist:

> brauchen, brauchte, bräuchte

Die Duden-Grammatik (8. Auflage) sagt zu *brauchen*:

> Im Konjunktiv II wird der Stammvokal heute oft – in der gesprochenen Sprache sogar regelmäßig – umgelautet (*bräuchte* statt *brauchte*). (§ 647)

Man darf sich aussuchen, welche dieser Verben man als *schwach* bezeichnen möchte. Im engeren Sinn (Endung *-te*, regelmäßig) nur *brauchen*, im weiteren Sinn (Endung *-te*, unregelmäßig) auch alle anderen genannten und sogar *haben*.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Ich würde diese als gemischte Verben (Änderung des Stammvokals aber Präteritum auf -te) klassifizieren, aber ich glaube, daß enthüllt genau den Kern des Problems!

Comment: Die vier letztgenannten heißen Präterito-Präsentien, weil ihr Kennzeichen ist, dass der Präsens Singular in der 1. und 3. Person nicht auf -e endet und darin einem starken Präteritum gleicht.

Comment: *Gemischt* kenne ich für Verben, bei denen das Präteritum -t, aber das Partizip -en hat: *salzen, salzte, gesalzen* und *mahlen, mahlte, gemahlen*.

Comment: @DavidVogt  Ja. Es scheint da verschiedene Definitionen zu geben, von denen nur manche zu der von mir angenommenen Regel führen.